# What is a 'pernicious' wrong belief?

Tags: wrongview

Under six major wrong doings (Abhithanani) in Buddhism,
(i. matricide, ii. patricide, iii. the murder of arahants (the Consummate Ones), iv. the shedding of the Buddha's blood, v. causing schism in the Sangha, and vi. pernicious false beliefs (niyata micca ditthi)),

> vi. pernicious false beliefs (niyata micca ditthi)

is mentioned in http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.2.01.piya.html.

What is the definition of a pernicious false belief and
why is it considered such a severe offense to be in the same level as other acts?

Comment: pernicious false belief (aka "positively mistaken belief") is a wrong view (explained elsewhere) that one is firmly established in. You said you were not seeking a definition of wrong view. Is your question about the "firmly established" part then?

Comment: yeah how can one be firmly established in wrong view and why is it severe as others mentioned here?

Comment: ok this seems pretty obvious then, I will leave it for others to answer. I'm more interested in "what is wrong view" question ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the commentary to that sutta doesn't use the term '*niyatamicchādiṭṭhi*' for the sixth abhithana, it uses the term '*aññasatthāruddesa*', which means 'proclaiming another teacher', i.e. setting oneself up as a student of a teacher with views outside of the Buddha's teaching, something an enlightened being cannot do (*abhabba kātuṃ*).

As to what the term '*niyatamicchādiṭṭhi*' (pernicious wrong belief) means, the MN tika says:

> *ahetukadiṭṭhiakiriyadiṭṭhinatthikadiṭṭhiyova niyatabhāvaṃ pattā niyatamicchādiṭṭhidhammā.*
>
> Views such as the view of causelessness, the view of non-action, or the view of nihilism, when fallen into a state of certainty are called states of pernicious wrong view.
>
> *(MN-t 22)*

Basically, the meaning is that any wrong view becomes 'pernicious' when it is clung to as a certainty.

Answer (score 1):

If you commit any of the 1st 5 (panchanathariya) you still can liberate your self from Samsara. If you have committed the 5 grave offenses, you will get definite results in the next birth. Most likely result is that you will be born in Avichi Hell. (Ajasath being a exception after doing so much good after words. ) At some stage this karma will end and by practicing the Dhamma you can come out of Samsara.

If you hold on to wrong views and do not practice the Dhamma. Then there is no way out of Samsara.

In order to practice of course your should have confidence in the teacher, the practice and your ability to practice and get results. If your faith is else where your will not practice the path leading you out of Samsara (you will be going something else instead), hence will be struck in it for ever, even though someone have done a grave offence in a part life can get enlightened in a later life getting inspired to practice the right path leading out of Samsara.